# Javascript Class Getter Setter

Tags: javascript, webpack, getter-setter

I try to use getter setter in javascript class with webpack

why.js

```
class why {
    set setWhy(answer) {
        this._answer = answer
    }

    get getWhy() {
        return this._answer
    }
}

export default why
```

index.js

```
import why from'./why.js'

const index = () => {
    why.setWhy = 'i dont know'
    console.log(why.getWhy)
}
```

but it returns undefined why ?

[undefined result in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inCIa.png)

Comment: `why` is a class. Create a instance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an object of the why class to make the above code work: 
 whyObject = new why();

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const index = () => {
    const whyInst = new why();
    whyInst.setWhy = 'i dont know'
    console.log(whyInst.getWhy)
}
```

Comment: if the answer was useful for you you can mark it as answer or upvote.